# byte array in arduino library

Tags: parsing, arduino, byte

ok so here is one for you maybe simple but i am not so sure.

i have the following code and it may be clear what i wish to  do by looking at the code.

Arduino.ino

```
   RF myRF;  //Creation of RF class.
   const int dataSize = 500;
   byte storedData[dataSize];

   //array is populated through program then the following is called

   myRF.populate(storedData);
```

RF.CCP

```
   const int dataSize = 500; 
   byte recivedData[dataSize];

   void RF::populate(byte reciveddata){
   recivedData = reciveddata;
   }
```

RF.H

```
 #include Arduino.h
 #ifndef RF_H
 #define RF_H

 class RF { 
     public:
       RF();
       ~RF();
void recive();
void send();
void print();
void sendnew(byte Storeddata);
 };

#endif
```

this is however producing an error "byte is not declared"

Hope its clear what i intend to do and hope you can help thanks.

Comment: what if you put unsigned char instead of byte? And... you forgot to say WHERE it is complaining...

Comment: on which section the .h file or .ccp

Comment: ok so have added arduino.h to the header file but I'm now getting this error:


      incompatible types in assignment of 'byte {aka unsigned char}' to 'byte      [300] {aka unsigned char [300]}'

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your files:

h file:

```
 #include Arduino.h
```

You should write

```
 #include <Arduino.h>
```

c file:

```
const int dataSize = 500; 
byte recivedData[dataSize];

void RF::populate(byte reciveddata){
recivedData = reciveddata;
}
```

Here you have a big problem. You are declaring recivedData here, but you want to assign it a value coming from another part of the program. This is not how it works.

IMO you have two ways to do this.

1) store just the pointer to the memory; this way is faster and occupies less memory than solution 2, but you have to ensure that the `storedData` variable you pass in the .ino file is not changed during the function

```
#include "RF.h" // I hope you already included this
byte *recivedData;

void RF::populate(byte *reciveddata){
recivedData = reciveddata;
}
```

2) copy the content of the received array to this array; this way you have a copy of the array, so you occupy twice the memory (but you can edit `storedData` without problems).

```
#include "RF.h" // I hope you already included this
const int dataSize = 500; 
byte recivedData[dataSize];
int recivedDataLength;

void RF::populate(byte *reciveddata, int reciveddatalength){
recivedDataLength = (reciveddatalength>dataSize) ? dataSize : reciveddatalength;
for (int i = 0; i < recivedDataLength; i++)
    recivedData[i] = reciveddata[i];
}
```